# Jhipster - Creating a relationship between JHI_User and another Entity ERROR

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster, reducers, jdl

I generated a Jhipster configured hereafter (Spring boot / React ).

In order to add some additional information to User Registration, I tried to follow this Tip published on Jhipster website : https://www.jhipster.tech/tips/022_tip_registering_user_with_additional_information.html

I already have an entity called "Client" that I want to use it as extra for User registration.

I started by creating a Relationship between **Client** and **JHI_User**, and here i'm stuck.

The command to edit an entity : Jhipster entity client

then, this was my entries to the inquiries

[image]

But, this error about JHI_User reducer i couldn't figure out :

[image]

Any idea ? Someone succeeded such thing ?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `User` instead of `JHI_User`. For example, if you were to use JDL instead of the console to generate your entities you would do something like this:

```java
relationship OneToOne {
    Client{registerUser} to User{clientUser}
}
```

Comment: Thank you, using "User" instead of "JHI_User" fixed the issue ;)